# LayoutParams don't work

Tags: android

I create table with two cells and one divider. Set LayoutParams for each  element.

Set margin and width but it don't work. I set LayoutParams for TextView and get this error,

```
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): Process: bairro.lettersgenerator, PID: 4144
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:587)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:576)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:474)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:439)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-20 07:16:14.320: E/AndroidRuntime(4144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Also I set divider with fix width but it does nothing

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams table_params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
table_params.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
table_params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
table_params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
table.setLayoutParams(table_params);
table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
table.setBackgroundColor(new Color().rgb(255, 255, 130));
PrintLog.p("i", ((TableLayout.LayoutParams)table.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin);

TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams tr_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
tr_params.leftMargin = 1;
tr.setLayoutParams(tr_params);
tr.setBackgroundColor(new Color().rgb(0, 255, 0));

TextView txt_cell_1 = new TextView(this);
//txt_cell_1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
txt_cell_1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txt_cell_1.setTextSize(40);
txt_cell_1.setText("1");

TextView txt_cell_2 = new TextView(this);
//txt_cell_2.setLayoutParams(txt_cell_1.getLayoutParams());
txt_cell_2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
txt_cell_2.setTextSize(40);
txt_cell_2.setText("1");

LinearLayout devider_cells = new LinearLayout(this);
devider_cells.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
devider_cells.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams devider_cells_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
devider_cells.setLayoutParams(devider_cells_params);
devider_cells.setBackgroundColor(new Color().rgb(255, 255, 255));

tr.addView(txt_cell_1);
tr.addView(devider_cells);
tr.addView(txt_cell_2);
table.addView(tr);

setContentView(table);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, attach more logs in the post the exception seems to be something else.

Comment: this is not your error, please post your entire log

Comment: try debugging ,use break points in each  row and check which line is giving the errors and this looks like prob with `LayoutParams` ( problem with no of col and rows)

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is causing the error (you need to replace it!!!). This is what I understood after referring this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19343)

```
table.setLayoutParams(table_params);
table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
```

You need to change it to

```
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

hope this well help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you CAN have TableRow.LayoutParams is a special case which is valid without width and height. This seems OK.

What I am concerned is the line:
txt_cell_2.setLayoutParams(txt_cell_1.getLayoutParams());

This may be not what Android likes. If you really want to avoid duplicate initialization by using single LayoutParams for two TextView's (*which I don't recommend*), try the following:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams commonParms 
   = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
         ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ....
    txt_cell_1.setLayoutParams(commonParms);

    ....
    txt_cell_2.setLayoutParams(commonParms);
```

I guess, in this case the system each time will convert ViewGroup.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParam, so you will have two instances of LayoutParam's "under cover" :)